# Setting initial state of UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch in the settings menu in my app and I am having difficulties trying to get the initial state to be 'on'. Even if I set the initial state to be 'on' in the attributes inspector, it still sets it to 'off' when the is opened for the first time.

Basically at the moment, the switch will be set to 'off' when the app opened for the first time however it does save the state if you change it so that works fine.

Here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func dupOffOnSwitch(sender: AnyObject) {
    if dupSwitch.on == true {
        autoAdjust = true
        println(autoAdjust)
    } else {
        autoAdjust = false
        println(autoAdjust)
    }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    dupSwitch.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings")
    println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings"))
}
```

'autoAdjust' is declared under import UIKit as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings")` to `true` for the first time you ever launch your app, you can replace the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your AppDelegate class with this code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

    //If app has never been launched...
    if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isNotFirstLaunch") {
        //Set autoAdjustSettings and isNotFirstLaunch to true
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "autoAdjustSettings")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isNotFirstLaunch")

        //Sync NSUserDefaults
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    return true
}
```

Of course, you can do the previous code in your UIViewController subclass but the AppDelegate should be the place for those settings.

Once done, your UIViewController subclass should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dupSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func dupOffOnSwitch(sender: AnyObject) {
        dupSwitch.on = (sender as UISwitch).on //Bool
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(dupSwitch.on, forKey: "autoAdjustSettings")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dupSwitch.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Unless you have a good reason to, I don't think you need to use the `viewWillAppear:` method in your UIViewController subclass for your NSUserDefaults statements. `viewDidLoad:` should be the right place for that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by adding this:

```
    dupSwitch.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings")
    println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings"))

    userReturnedAuto = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userReturnedAuto")
    if userReturnedAuto == false {
        dupSwitch.on = true
        userReturnedAuto = true
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(userReturnedAuto, forKey: "userReturnedAuto")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(userReturnedAuto, forKey: "autoAdjustSettings")
    }
```

Probably not the ideal solution but it works.

Comment: What is the purpose of `userReturnedAuto`? To initialize `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings")` the first time ever the app is launched?

Comment: @POB Yes. Since I couldn't get the UISwitch to be set to 'on' initially, I just put it in that if so that the first time the app is launched it turns it on and then after that it is just down to whatever the user has chosen.

Comment: OK. So your code is fine. If you want to check another way to write your code, you can check my answer.